# Online Microdata parser

Tags: web-apps, html

I‘m looking for an online/hosted [Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) parser.

Bonus points if it also validates vocabulary use (for known vocabularies, especially [Schema.org](http://schema.org/)), e.g., it could report an error if a non-existing Schema.org type or property is used.

**Input**: Direct input (full HTML5 document or only a HTML5 snippet) or URL to a HTML5 document.

**Output**: The Microdata items and their properties in a human-readable form. If a property has another item as value, it should either nest it or reference it (e.g., via "Item 1", "Item 2" etc.).

#### What I tried:

- [foolip.org Live Microdata](http://foolip.org/microdatajs/live/): Outputs only JSON, which is not easy to read (or a SERP snippet, vCard or iCal, if the respective vocabularies are used).
- [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets): Good presentation, but it reports warnings/errors about vocabulary use (Schema.org in their case), which [aren’t *actual* errors](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58912/17633), it’s just that the input doesn’t comply with Google’s own rules for displaying their Rich Snippets.
- [Gregg Kellogg RDF Distiller](http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/distiller): Outputs/converts only various RDF formats, JSON etc.
- [W3C Microdata to RDF Distiller](http://www.w3.org/2012/pyMicrodata/): Outputs only RDF (as Turtle, RDF/XML, JSON-LD, or N-Triples).
- [Yandex Structured data validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml): While it doesn’t seem to report false errors, the presentation is not so good (property names and values are not aligned, not enough padding, no visual difference between property name and value).

Answer (score 2):

[**Structured Data Linter**

http://linter.structured-data.org/](http://linter.structured-data.org/)

(The [code is FLOSS/public domain](https://github.com/structured-data/linter).)

**Input**: directly (even allows snippets), file upload, URL.

**Output**: As table. Item values are nested. If the same property is used several times, the values are displayed in a list.

[image: Raw structured data extracted from the input snippet, presented in a table which contains another table for an item value.]

It has ["limited vocabulary validation"](http://linter.structured-data.org/about/) for several vocabularies, including Schema.org.

Possible issue: It does not only parse the Microdata, but also RDFa (and JSON-LD, but not if it’s embedded in a `script` element). Even if the input only contains Microdata, the tool displays the result *as* RDF (e.g., using `rdf:type` for the `itemtype`).